# Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range while working with string arrays

Tags: excel, runtime-error, arrays, subscript, vba

I'm new to vba script. I am trying to write a function below but couldn't make it out successfully. I really appreciate any help I can get on this.

The code is:

```
Option Explicit

Dim status As String

Sub StartModule()
Dim index As Integer
Dim result As String
Dim a As Integer
Dim Name As Variant

Range("D4").Value = 1
Range("D5").Value = 5
Range("D6").Value = 9
Range("D7").Value = 2

Dim o: Set o = CreateObject("NAddIn.Functions")
status = ""

Do Until status = "DADA"
    result = o.getRandomNumber
    Name = Split(result, ",")

    If Trim(Name(3)) = Trim(Range("D4").Value) Then
        Range("C4").Value = "one"
    End If
    If Trim(Name(3)) = Trim(Range("D5").Value) Then
        Range("C5").Value = "five"
    End If
    If Trim(Name(3)) = Trim(Range("D6").Value) Then
        Range("C4").Value = "nine"
    End If
    If Trim(Name(3)) = Trim(Range("D7").Value) Then
        Range("C7").Value = "two"
    End If

    Wait 1 '<~~ Wait for a second
    If status = "EXIT" Then Exit Do
Loop

End Sub

Sub StopModule()
    status = "EXIT"
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

This vba script is calling a `getRandomNumber()` which is a user defined function in dll file.  It generates string of random numbers in the range(1,10); Then the thrid random number in the string is compared with cell values in excel to update cells in excel with some string values.

Bu,the problem is I am getting an error `Run-time error 9: Subscript out of range` at  line `If Trim(Name(3)) = Trim(Range("D4").Value)` then.

Comment: name(3) is equal to nothing, was declared but the is no name(i)= ...  Same goes for status, be ready for infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

> Then the thrid random number in the string is compared with cell
>   values in excel to update cells in excel with some string values.

You're comparing fourth random number. Your 'Name' elements are (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),...
I suppose there is no element Name(3) as you're getting 'out of range' error.